# Python - Multistep sort descending

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I'm attempting to sort a list of tuples.  The sort must pass through multiple steps.  The steps are:

```
(1) Sort descending based on second element of tuple
(2) Sort descending based on string length of first element of tuple
(3) Sort ascending lexicographical order
```

So, for example, the list:

```
[('ident', 3), (')', 2), ('(', 2), (';', 2), ('string', 1), ('}', 1), ('char', 1), ('=', 1), ('{', 1)]
```

Should be sorted as:

```
[('ident', 3), ('(', 2),  (')', 2), (';', 2), ('string', 1), ('char', 1),  ('=', 1), ('{', 1), ('}', 1)]
```

My attempt was:

```
theList = sorted(theList, key=lambda x: (x[1], len(x[0]), x[0]))
```

But that didn't produce the desired output, I want something like:

```
theList = sorted(theList, key=lambda x: (x[1].descending(), len(x[0]).descending(), x[0].ascending()))
```

What is the correct syntax for achieving this?

Comment: What you mean by `-x[0]`?

Comment: It was suggested in another post.  I want the order to be descending instead of ascending.

Comment: If I do that it reverses the entire list.  I only want to reverse the part that corresponds to x[0]

Comment: The question is misleading: in your desired output, the lexicographic sort is really *ascending*  because `ord('(') < ord(')') < ord(';')`.  So the three steps should read descending, descending, ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> l = [('ident', 3), (')', 2), ('(', 2), (';', 2), ('string', 1), ('}', 1), ('char', 1), ('=', 1), ('{', 1)]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-x[1], -len(x[0]), x[0]))
[('ident', 3), ('(', 2), (')', 2), (';', 2), ('string', 1), ('char', 1), ('=', 1), ('{', 1), ('}', 1)]
```

**EDIT:**

From your expected output `('=', 1), ('{', 1), ('}', 1)` this is an ascending lexicographical order, check this out:

```
>>> c = ['}','=','{']
>>> map(ord, c)
[125, 61, 123]
>>> sorted(c)
['=', '{', '}'] #what you want to get
>>> map(ord, sorted(c))
[61, 123, 125] #Ascending order
```

If you want it in descending lexicographical order, you can the following:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-x[1], -len(x[0]), -ord(x[0][0])))
[('ident', 3), (';', 2), (')', 2), ('(', 2), ('string', 1), ('char', 1), ('}', 1), ('{', 1), ('=', 1)]
```

Comment: Actually, what you put in your expected output, is the ascending not descending lexicographical order...

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @VictorBrunell...no pblm, check my edit, to clear stuff in your mind